# Trying to run and debug

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to run and debug my code/ see it in a Chrome browser to see my progression and the console in the webpage to see if my JS stuff is there.  I have a debugger for Chrome installed and and a live server.  Now when I go into run menu and click the first option, it just pulls up my extensions in an editor.  Before I added a live server I was getting a message that local host was not available.  Do I need to put my html and js files in a separate folder or somehow separate them so the editor know I just want to see them?  Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Ok thanks isherwood,   I have Auto-save on Windows Change-Yuri Zaporozhchenko, Debugger for Chrome, and Live Server-Ritwick Day.  After trying to run/debug to see results these are the comments I see.

Comment: Ok thanks isherwood,   I have Auto-save on Windows Change-Yuri Zaporozhchenko, Debugger for Chrome, and Live Server-Ritwick Day.  After trying to run/debug to see results these are the comments I see.  First 5 lines of comments "type": chrome  "request": attach "name: "Attach to Chrome" "port":9222   webRoot;"${workspaceFolder}"  Second grouping of code after asking VS code to run and debug is:  "type": "node"; "request": "launch", "name": "Launch Program"; "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js; "skip files":[ "<node_internals?>/**".  The Add Configuration button it present.  Thank you.